# Joomla 3.4.8 update to 3.5 giving 'Uncaught TypeError: window.pingExtract is not a function' in console

Tags: joomla-3.4, update, joomla-3.5

While trying to update my Joomla instance on my native environment in OSX Yosemite 10.10.5. I am brought to the "updating" page where the progress bar shows up and a message that says 'Updating your Joomla files. Please wait ...' but nothing happens. I looked in my server log files but found nothing unusual, however I do get an error in the browser console on the 'updating' page that says -

```
Uncaught TypeError: window.pingExtract is not a function
```

Comment: I would just clear Joomla and browser cache, restart browser and tried again.

Comment: Tried all these things with no luck

Comment: Found out something [here](https://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/6769) but have not a solution, have you tried now with Joomla 3.5.1? Have you tried to just leave the browser for a long time on "Please wait.."? It could be processing the update but not showing progess bar due to the javascript error.

Comment: I tried both 3.5 and 3.5.1 but no luck. I did find this [link](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=706&t=917251) which describes my problem exactly.

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same issue on two 3.5.0 instances.

Turns out that media/com_joomlaupdate was missing the /js directory.  The file update.js in the /js directory is what declares pingExtract

I downloaded the full package of Joomla extracted the directory and placed it where it in media/com_joomlaupdate and it resolved the issue.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I tried adding the JS directory and to the com_joomlaupdate folder and ran the updater again. I ended up getting a different error message than before having to do with my database configuration. I was on a tight deadline so I created a new Joomla instance and moved my template over. Any idea why the folder went missing?

Comment: My guess would be something to do with the updater Joomla when I updated to 3.5. Maybe the updater removed the directories but failed to apply fresher copies? Since I performed the same update on two separate instances and the got the same results I am willing to bet it has to do with the updater/how I perform updates. Glad you got a solution working though!