# Joomla An error has occurred. 0 JForm::validateField() rule `number` missing. Return to Control Panel

Tags: joomla-3.4

Got

> An error has occurred. 0 JForm::validateField() rule `number` missing.  Return to Control Panel

while tying to change email id and Name from mail settings in joomla's  Global Configuration>Server
how to fix this problem? 
Ned help

Comment: Can you update joomla to the latest version? Other users who had this issue got it solved simply updating the cms.

Comment: @NicolaCiciliot; when i try to update to 3.5.1 the page just shows **Updating your Joomla files. Please wait ... 
Percent complete
Bytes read
Bytes extracted
Files extracted**
and there is no progress

Comment: Have you tried using this [solution to update Joomla](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/16031/joomla-3-4-8-update-to-3-5-giving-uncaught-typeerror-window-pingextract-is-not) as suggested in your other question by @FFrewin?

Comment: You might want to take a look at your file permissions just to be sure the problem is not there. Specifically coniguration.php file.